# Changing NetBeans auto-generated code

Tags: templates, netbeans, auto-generate

NetBeans has some great features in it like auto-generating code.  However there are some things missing which I would like to change.  One of my practises is to add comments to the generated code telling me what it is.  For example say that I am writing in php and auto generate a constructor for an object.  The end result would be auto generated like this:

```
function __construct(){};
```

However what if I wanted NetBeans to generate comments alongside it like this:

```
//constructor
function __construct(){};
```

Is it possible to change something in NetBeans to make this happen?  Templates maybe?  And if so which template file and how should I change it to suit my needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to Tools->Options->Editor->Code Templetes.
You choose language php.
There you can see the templates. You can change them or add yours.

Comment: In NetBeans 7.2:  Tools->Templates.  In the Template Manager window, select the language and then you can see the templates.